# ARIA - How to announce "label", "heading" etc?

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

In my Angular application I have a part of a page which looks like this:

```
...
<label class="checkbox-container> <!-- because I want the whole box to be clickable -->
   <input type="checkbox" .../>
   <div class="checkbox-label">{{ checkboxLabel }}</div>
   <div class="checkbox-text">{{ checkboxText }}</div>
</label>
...
```

When a screen reader is reading the page, I would like it to somehow announce the card label by saying "label" or "heading" or something like that, so the user knows it is not an "ordinary" piece of text. I tried wrapping it into `<label></label>` or `<h1></h1>`, as well as giving it `aria-label="Heading"`, but it didn't work. So is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do like this.

- div as a container (depending on your design).
- label in its "correct" place
- add a pseudo element (`::before`, `::after`) to the label, with `position: absolute;`. This will make the full card clickable

This is a common approach when working with links and making the whole card clickable. I recommend reading this [post](https://inclusive-components.design/cards/) by Heydon Pickering

As you can notice I just made the bare minimum of style to make the point. This could be done with `display: grid;` and if so you can skip the `.checkbox__content` div.

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox__label {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.checkbox__label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="something">

  <div class="checkbox__content">
    <label for="something" class="checkbox__label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>

    <p class="checkbox__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi sit quae commodi eos quo dolor, nisi at iste temporibus iusto.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```